# How to make an ((NSErrorPointer -> NSData!)!) closure in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures, archiving, zipzap

I'm trying to use the [ZipZap](https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap) method

```
ZZArchiveEntry(fileName: String!, compress: Bool, dataBlock: ((NSErrorPointer) -> NSData!)!)
```

in Swift, but can't figure out the right syntax for the dataBlock closure. 
I tried the following code:

```
let fileEntry = ZZArchiveEntry(fileName: "test.txt", compress: true, dataBlock: {
            (error: NSErrorPointer) in
            return "test".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        })
```

which leads to the following error:

```
Cannot find an initializer for type 'ZZArchiveEntry' that accepts an argument list of type '(fileName: String, compress: Bool, dataBlock: (NSErrorPointer) -> _)'
```

Are such closures possible, and if yes, how in Xcode 7.0 beta 3?

Comment: Replace `(error: NSErrorPointer)` with `(error: NSErrorPointer) -> NSData!` or `error` and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning an unwrapped optional `NSData` (i.e. you're returning a non-optional) and the compiler is just getting confused.

You can resolve it by staging the value in a variable:

```
let fileEntry = ZZArchiveEntry(fileName: "test.txt", compress: true, dataBlock: {
    (error: NSErrorPointer) in
    let data = "test".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    return data
})
```

Or, because expected return type of that closure is an optional, if you remove that `!`, the error goes away:

```
let fileEntry = ZZArchiveEntry(fileName: "test.txt", compress: true, dataBlock: {
    (error: NSErrorPointer) in
    return "test".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
})
```

Or, as others have pointed out, you can simplify this further:

```
let fileEntry = ZZArchiveEntry(fileName: "test.txt", compress: true) { error in
    return "test".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Swift's trailing closure syntax, like this:

```
let fileEntry = ZZArchiveEntry(fileName: "test.txt", compress: true) { (error) -> NSData! in
    return ("test" as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
}
```

Or more simply:

```
let fileEntry = ZZArchiveEntry(fileName: "test.txt", compress: true) { error in
    ("test" as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
}
```

You'll also need to explicitly cast `"test"` to `NSString` to use the `dataUsingEncoding(_:)` method.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, Xcode can automatically write closure for you. For that select closure with e.g pressing Tab button and you will see this:

[image]

And then press the Enter key on keyboard and Xcode will write all the brackets and needed parameters.
[image]